# Sentry not working with lombok logging (with version 1.7.30 Sentry)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, sentry

I am trying to set up sentry in my project with version 1.7.30. It is a spring boot project with gradle, i am using the sentry spring boot starter dependency with:

```
implementation group: 'io.sentry', name: 'sentry-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.7.30'
implementation group: 'io.sentry', name: 'sentry-logback', version: '1.7.30'
```

I have a company sentry dashboard for this version. I have set the DNS in application.properties. My application.properties look like this:

```
sentry.dsn=xxxxx
```

I am able to capture the exception with `Sentry.capture(e)` any where, but while using lombok, with @Slf4j annotation logging, with `log.error(e)` I am unable to capture exception and its not reflecting in my dashboard. I have tried it with version 4.3 and it was working in that. But once i came to version 1.7.30 i am only able to do it manually with `Sentry.capture()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing configuration options from Sentry SDK 3.x+ with Sentry 1.7.x. Sentry + Logback auto-configuration and properties like `sentry.logging.minimum-event-level` works only in the new SDK.

If you must use 1.7.x you have to configure Logback appender in `logback.xml`.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/legacy/logback/